# Deploy playframework application on heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am trying to deploy a playframework application to Heroku. After deploying, I trying to access the URL Heroku gave me, it only show a welcome page as below :

Heroku | Welcome to your new app!
Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying.

Is any wrong ??

Comment: It looks like your app didn't deploy.  What was the output doing a `git push heroku master`?

Comment: i did git push heroku master actually ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is not recognized by Heroku (Heroku does not know how to start your app).

You need to create a file called `Procfile` in the top directory of your Play! application:

```
web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

You will more details in [this documentation](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/8/29/play/).

Comment: it's a possible problem i think about. If I have a normal play app, how do I setup the Procfile, is it like : "web: play run --http.port=$80" or "web: play run --http.port=80". What is the format of Procfile? Thank you.

Comment: just leave the Procfile as it is, with $PORT and $PLAY_OPTS, these are Heroku internals.

Comment: so it is " web: play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS " ?? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks! For adding the Procfile, the app deployed perfectly!